# Como puedo mantener la misma altura y ancho en un componente (@Composable function) en jetpack compose Android

Tags: android, jetpack-compose

Tengo la siguiente @Composable function la cual mustra imágenes y texto, sin embargo algunas cards se ven de diferente tamaño y quiero que todas se vean del mismo tamaño independientemente del contenido, actualmente me pasa esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del componente:

```
@Composable
fun CardHome(clickable:()->Unit,text:String,image: Any?){

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(15.dp)
            .clickable { clickable() },
        elevation = 10.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        ) {

            AsyncImage(model = image, contentDescription = "${UUID.randomUUID()}", alignment = Alignment.Center, contentScale = ContentScale.Inside)
            Text(text = text, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(5.dp),
                style= TextStyle(color = Azul2, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, fontSize = 15.sp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
    }
}
```

Como hacer para que sean del mismo tamaño ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se podía lograr usando :  Modifier.weight(1f).aspectRatio(1f):

```
@Composable
fun CardHome(
    modifier: Modifier,
    clickable: () -> Unit,
    text: String,
    image: Any?
) {

    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
        onClick = clickable
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        ) {

            AsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f),
                model = image,
                contentDescription = "${UUID.randomUUID()}",
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Inside
            )
            Text(
                text = text, modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}


Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(10.dp)
) {
    CardHome(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .aspectRatio(1f),
        clickable = { /*TODO*/ },
        text = "Hello World",
        image = R.drawable.landscape1
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
    CardHome(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .aspectRatio(1f),
        clickable = { /*TODO*/ },
        text = "Hello World",
        image = R.drawable.landscape2
    )
}
```